# hibernate @TableGenerator in error after enabling maven porfiles in a java project

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, profile

I have enabled maven profiles in a maven porject and after doing this I had an error in eclipse saying:

No generator named "UserIdGenerator" is defined in the persistence unit

I have the enity Id-s in my java hibernate project generated by @TableGenerator.

I have to mention that the aplication builds and deply ok event with this error.

There must be some porblem in eclipse that is looking wrongly to a persistence unit or something like that.

I am using eclipse kepler. The maven profiles are defined like this:

```
<profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/local</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>devel</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/devel</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/prod</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
   </profiles>
```

Comment: are you sure eclipse is saying "****"? how come eclipse is showing asterisks.

Comment: It is just a generic generator name which i chose ... for example "UserIdGenerator"